# How to develop and run app for office 2013?

Tags: office-2013

I want to develop some app for office 2013. my problem is when i searched for `microsoft developer tools office 2013` i find only that link [OfficeDevToolsForVS2012](http://aka.ms/OfficeDevToolsForVS2012) . That link is all over the blogs even on microsoft site [msdn.microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apps/fp123627.aspx) . The downloaded file run `Web Platform API` but it tells me that it can't find that product(i don't know how even i get it from microsoft link). So i want to know how to develop app for office using vs2012.

UPDATE**:

I found some exe file called `officetools_bundle.exe` that installed the required tools but when i run anything even the online samples i get this error

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved not, but i still don't know what's the reason behind it.

All i did is i installed fresh Windows 7 64bit  on my machine and then every thing is working like charm.